# Magick++ - JPEG compressed TIFF

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I have a problem creating a TIFF image with a JPEG compression using Magick++, the C++ API of ImageMagick. When I use the convert tool the following way, it works:

```
convert 1.jpg -compress JPEG 1.tiff
```

When I want to do the same in C++, it looks like this:

```
Image img("1.jpg");
img.compressType(JPEGCompression);
img.write("1.tiff");
```

But this code does **not** work. It throws an exception when it tries to generate the file "1.tiff":

```
Unhandled exception at 0x74ecb727 in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Magick::ErrorCoder at memory location 0x002ffc2c..
```

It points to **Line 103** in file **Thread.cpp**

Is this a bug or is something wrong with my code?

**Update**

I changed the code to this:

```
try{
    Image img(Desktop+"1.jpg");
    img.compressType(JPEGCompression);
    img.write(Desktop+"1.tiff");
}catch(Exception e){
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Output:
test.exe: CompressionNotSupported `JPEG' @ error/tiff.c/WriteTIFFImage/2611

So... it seems to be not supported. The question is: Why does he convert tool support it then? Does someone know a way to do it?

**Update**

I've created an empty new project, recompiled ImageMagick and then added the following settings:

additional include dirs:

```
c:/imagemagick/magick++/lib;c:/imagemagick/
```

additional lib dirs:

```
c:/imagemagick/visualmagick/lib/
```

libs:

```
CORE_RL_bzlib_.lib;CORE_RL_coders_.lib;CORE_RL_filters_.lib;CORE_RL_jbig_.lib;CORE_RL_jp2_.lib;CORE_RL_jpeg_.lib;CORE_RL_lcms_.lib;CORE_RL_libxml_.lib;CORE_RL_magick_.lib;CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib;CORE_RL_png_.lib;CORE_RL_tiff_.lib;CORE_RL_ttf_.lib;CORE_RL_wand_.lib;CORE_RL_xlib_.lib;CORE_RL_zlib_.lib;CORE_RL_wmf_.lib;X11.lib;Xext.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;wsock32.lib;winmm.lib;
```

and then tried to run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main() {
    Image img("c:/users/patrik stutz/Desktop/1.jpg");
    img.compressType(JPEGCompression);
    img.write("c:/users/patrik stutz/Desktop/1.tiff");
    return 0;
}
```

And it worked!! All using VS2010. I have no clue why it didn´t work in my other project with the same settings...

Comment: What is happening if you don't change the compressType? The command line tool seems seems to save TIFFs with JPEG compression automatically when you use a JPEG file as input.

Comment: How do your `LDFLAGS` looks like?

Comment: @aeby: what do you mean with that?

Comment: How do you compile your source? I tried your example with the following compiler args: `g++ -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/X11 -o"testim"  ./src/testim.o   -lMagick++ -lMagickWand -lMagickCore -llcms -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -llqr-1 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -lbz2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread -lltdl`

Comment: I´m compiling the project using the Magick++ .h & .lib files. Commandline args are: /I"C:\" /I"c:/ImageMagick/" /I"C:\ImageMagick\Magick++\lib" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oi /Oy- /GL /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm- /EHa /MT /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Release\FILEminimizer PDF.pch" /Fa"Release\" /Fo"Release\" /Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [ImageMagick Image Formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) you need the [jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz](http://www.ijg.org/files/) for jpeg suppport. You have to link with `libjpeg` and `libtiff` to get it working. You can create all necessary linker flags using this command:

```
Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs
```

For me the following code is working:

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main() {
    Image img("1.jpg");
    img.compressType(JPEGCompression);
    img.write("1.tiff");
    return 0;
}
```

Using this compiler command:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/X11 -o"testim"  ./src/testim.o -lMagick++ -lMagickWand -lMagickCore -llcms -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -llqr-1 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lXext -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXt -lbz2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread -lltdl
```

**Update**: I just saw that your error is originated by your tiff library. ImageMagick uses `TIFFGetConfiguredCODECs()` the get the supported compression codecs. So your tiff library has to support JPEG compression. Maybe you can try to update your tiff library.

Comment: You are doing it using g++. Can you explain how I can do it using VC++ on Windows?

Comment: Did you use the [windows version](ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/windows/)? There is a folder `VisualMagick` with all needed libraries and project files for Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0

Comment: I´ve made a new empty project now and started from scratch. It works really well now. No clue why it didn´t work in the other project with the same settings... Thanks anyway ;) you´ll get the bounty!